# Understanding impersonation permissions

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, impersonation

I have an ASP.NET web application using Windows authentication and impersonation. Here's the relevant part of web.config:

```
<authentication mode="Windows"/>
<identity impersonate="true"/>
```

The application code now tries to access a file (`XDocument.Load`) that *the authenticated user has access to*. This **worked perfectly fine** until today we started getting the following exception instead:

```
System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path '...' is denied.
```

(Obviously, the admin tells me that "nothing has changed on the server".)

I was able to "fix" the issue by granting the *application pool identity* permission to the file. However, I don't understand *why* this fixed the problem.

My question: **If impersonation is used, why is it still necessary for the application pool identity to have access to the files used?** Do both the impersonated user and the application pool identity need access? Or only the application pool identity? If the latter, what's the point of impersonation?

Answer (score 1):

> The website accesses the disk by using the w3wp.exe worker process,
>   which is essentially the application pool. The identity set for that
>   app pool (e.g. IIS Apppool\Site001) is used in some situations on
>   disk.
>
> When using Windows authentication, the application pool identity (e.g.
>   IIS Apppool\Site001) is used for some access but the Windows account
>   (e.g. User1) is used for other access. It depends on the impersonation
>   settings of your application or framework that you’re using.
>   Therefore, you would generally need to grant access to the application
>   pool identity, plus every Windows account (e.g. User1, User2, User99)
>   which needs access to your site.

Here some quotes from [Scott Forsyth Article](http://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/iis-using-windows-authentication-with-minimal-permissions-granted-to-disk). If I understood you correctly this article should help.

Comment: Thanks, that was an interesting read. So I guess the answer to my question lies in the details of what the author summarizes as "some access" and "other access". Thus, +1 for pointing in the right direction, but no check mark because those details are missing. :-)